# How to create tables with dynamic name in sequelize and typescript and fetch from it

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, database, sequelize.js

I have a pos system, that should have multiple companies in one db referenced by company alias, but for each company I want to create an unique inventory table `{company_alias}_inventory`, how could I achieve so in **sequelize** and **Typescript** , and how to fetch from it?

Comment: What about creating the same table in different schemas one for each company to simplify a bit this process?

Comment: You mean create for each company the table manually? If that’s what you mean, then it’s not what I need. The pos system will be sold to random companies ( can’t predict each one)

Comment: Plus that all companies will have the same schema of table

Comment: I meant the format `schema.table_name` -> `company_alias.inventory`